# How to exclude categories from layered navigation by xml?

Tags: php, xml, magento-1.7

I found a suggestion how to do this in xml but as it does not work and I can only find ways to do it by changing core/local code, I'm posting here to see if anyone can shed some light on it.

this is the suggestion I found:

```
<reference name="catalog.leftnav">
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
</reference>
```

I added this to the catalog_category_default and _layered handles but with no result. On checking the core code it seemed the correct name for the alias should be layer_filter_category and so I changed to that on both handles but that didn't work either.

More as a desperation I also tried nesting reference in another reference to make sure it was loaded but I'm really unsure if this is correct at all?

```
<reference name="left">
    <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>layer_filter_category</alias></action>
    </reference>
</reference>
```

It would be much appreciated if anyone could let me know the correct way to do this by xml.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do it via XML you should edit catalog.xml

replace:

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" 
    after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" />
```

with this:

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">  
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
</block>
```

Comment: To set "Use in layered navigation" to False only works for attributes, not Categories as it's not an attribute per se.

I'll test to add the block handle to the action method as that is probably what's causing it to not work. I'm using local.xml for these changes so not sure how to do the update of the action method correctly?

Comment: For anyone else wondering I can confirm that adding the second block of code from Andrew's answer, to the catalog_category_default and _layered handles - work. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: Hi, i've edited my answer, I usually add these answers from memory without looking so sometimes I can be a little off, you could mark it as correct ;)